# Not returning something from Promise and function in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In pursuit of writing a nice clean code, I have created function where I am setting up things such as **`res.status()`** or sending **`res.send()`**

Now, In general I know, If we don't return anything in Javascript it returns undefined.

And probably if we create a promise and don't resolve it, it would cause **memory leak**?

But is this same for **`.then()`** i.e if we don't return anything in our .then and similarly  if we call function which sets things like **`res.status()`** and sends **`res.send()`**

To state an example, this is what i am doing

Consider this Api route and Middleware

```
router.use(MiddlewareAuth.eventBriteAuthentication)

router.get("/user", (req, res) => {
    eventBriteHelper.getEventbriteRequestedDataForAuthorizedUser("https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me", req.session.contextToken["EventbriteAccessToken"])
    .then(response => {
        res.send(response.data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        errorCodesHelper.errorStatusCodeAndResponseMeetupLoggedInUser(req, res, error)
    })
})
```

Here in,

```
errorCodesHelper.errorStatusCodeAndResponseMeetupLoggedInUser(req, res, error)
```

is this function

```
const errorStatusCodeAndResponseEventbriteLoggedInUser = (req, res, error) => {

    //Updaing the same in firebase
    if (req.user["eventbrite"] !== "warning") {
        FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb("users", req.user.email, {"eventbrite": "warning"})
        .catch(error => {
            throw error
        })
    req.user["eventbrite"] = "warning"
    }

    res.status(error.response.status)
    res.send(error.response.data.problem)
}
```

Is this okay?

And lastly,  In my meetup refresh token `.then()`, I am not returning anything.

```
  const meetupRefreshToken = (req, res) => {
   return helperFunctionsAxios.refreshingAccessToken("meetup", req, res)
        .then(response => {
            let expiryTime = authHelper.calculatingTokenExpiryTime(response.data.expires_in)   
            let TokenToStore = {"meetupRefreshToken": response.data.refresh_token, "meetupAccessToken": response.data.access_token, "meetup_expires_in": expiryTime }
            FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb("authentication", req.user.email, TokenToStore)
            .catch(err => {throw err})   
            req.session.contextToken = {...req.session.contextToken, ...TokenToStore}
        })
        .catch(error => {
            errorCodesHelper.errorStatusCodeAndResponseMeetupLoggedInUser(req, res, error)
        }) 
    }
```

Is this okay as well? If yes, then can someone please point a situation where not returning anything can cause memory leaks?

Answer (score 2):

> And probably if we create a promise and don't resolve it, it would cause memory leak?

Only if someone is hanging onto the returned promise indefinitely expecting it to resolve.

> But is this same for .then() i.e if we don't return anything in our .then and similarly if we call function which sets things like res.status() and sends res.send()

Not returning anything from a `.then()` handler is perfectly fine as long as the user of the promise isn't expecting a resolved value.  It just leaves the promise's resolved value as `undefined`.

> Consider this Api route and Middleware

That is perfectly fine.  You're using `.then()` and `.catch()` to know when an async operation is done and then you're sending the response in either case.  Nothing is using the final promise so it doesn't matter what its resolved value is.

> Is this [errorStatusCodeAndResponseEventbriteLoggedInUser function] okay?

That's a bit odd and has some problems.  It will generate warnings about uncaught rejections in some implementations.  It appears you're doing some sort of fire-and-forget with your call to `FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb()` where you aren't doing anything with the result whether it succeeds or not.  It's not clear to me why or what your intention is for that.  If it's just some sort of logging, then perhaps I could understand (I'd still put a `.then()` on it and not `throw` from the `.catch()` when nothing is listening to that).  But, if this is not supposed to a fire-and-forget implementation, then you're proceeding without waiting for the operation to finish.

> And lastly, In my meetup refresh token `.then()`, I am not returning anything.

As I said above, the only time not returning something from a `.then()` handler is a problem is when somebody is using the returned promise and is expecting a resolved value.  If the caller isn't expecting a resolved value, there's no need to return one.  The resolved value will just be `undefined` which is perfectly fine in Javascript.

This construction:

```
 .catch(err => {throw err})
```

is pointless.  Your code works just the same without that.  Either do something useful in the `.catch()` handler or omit it and let it percolate to the caller.

Also, in your last function you are again not waiting for `FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb()` to finish so this is essentially a new, unlinked promise chain that proceeds in a fire-and-forget mode.  It may create warnings for uncaught rejections.  This is not generally a good practice as it will fail silently and nobody will ever know and nothing waits for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer `FirebaseHelper.updateDataInDb()` about this line, Here I am updating data in the Database. I am used to using Mongoose which gives response in `.then()` after the updation in Database is completed. In contrast `firestore` does not and hence using `.then()` isn't required since I don't want to do anything with response. Does this makes sense? or am still doing something wrong? `.catch()` over there is throwing error because I am still pondering over what should be done if there is an error (will probably set `res.status to 500`. Do let me know if this is correct?